# Does a complete graph have an Euler circuit for n = 1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My thought was that a complete graph with only one vertex does not contain any edges, so it is vacuously true that it contains an Euler circuit. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

A connected graph has an Euler circuit if and only if all vertices has even degree.